# yo @microsoft/sharepoint fails on This generator (@microsoft/sharepoint:app) requires yeoman-environment at least 3.0.0, current version is 2.10.3

Tags: npm, sharepoint, gulp, yo

I have the following issue and I cannot fix it :

```
C:\project> yo @microsoft/sharepoint Error @microsoft/sharepoint

This generator (@microsoft/sharepoint:app) requires yeoman-environment at least 3.0.0,
current version is 2.10.3,
try reinstalling latest version of 'yo' or use '--ignore-version-check' option

I performed npm ls :
+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.13.0
+-- gulp@3.9.1
+-- gulp-cli@2.3.0
+-- touch-cli@0.0.1
+-- typescript@4.4.4
+-- yeoman-environment@3.0.0
`-- yo@3.1.0
```

Could you please help me? thank you!

Comment: Have you ever get the solution for this ? If yes, please suggest me. I am facing similar error and tried everything. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have a problem with the "path" with the user who used the computer before you, clean the modules in your C:\Users , clear node mdule in your file users in each user folder.

Comment: delete all module node and take off everything that is connected  in users .)) it helped me